SMT solvers for quantified nonlinear real arithmetic?
Currently I am implementing a probabilistic programming language that requires solving a lot of quantified real constraints. Most of these constraints are solvable using Z3, but the ones involving exponential constraints do not work. My understanding is that solving constraints involving exponentials is beyond the scope of most general purpose SMT solvers like Z3 and CVC5. On the other hand, the specialized DReal solver for real numbers does not implement quantifier elimination. Are there any better solvers or algorithms for quantified real arithmetic?

Possibly better asked in [proofassistants.SE].

What is an "exponential constraint"?  Can you define the language of such constraints formally?  Can you define your requirements more clearly?  "better" is vague.

The real exponential field is not even unconditionally known to be decidable. Are you looking for an SMT solver that assumes Schanuel's conjecture?
